# Bullets next to django multiple MultipleChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form with 2 MultipleChoiceField's with the CheckboxSelectMultiple widget.

When rendered in the template the checkboxs have a "bullet points" to the left of each choice.

I'm thinking it has to do with the checkboxs rending as an  but I'm not sure how to remove the bullet points?

Feedback is much appreciated.

**Form**

```
class GameScheduleForm(forms.Form):

    weight_training_days = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        choices=(
            (0, "MONDAY"),
            (1, "TUESDAY"),
            (2, "WEDNESDAY"),
            (3, "THURSDAY"),
            (4, "FRIDAY"),
            (5, "SATURDAY"),
            (6, "SUNDAY"),
        ),
    )

    cardio_training_days = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        choices=(
            (0, "MONDAY"),
            (1, "TUESDAY"),
            (2, "WEDNESDAY"),
            (3, "THURSDAY"),
            (4, "FRIDAY"),
            (5, "SATURDAY"),
            (6, "SUNDAY"),
        ),
    )
```

**Template**

```
{% extends "fitgames/fitgames_base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="well game span4 offset4">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <h4 class="text-center">Total Body HIT</h4>
            <p class="text-center">Select the days you can workout</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <form method="post" action="{% url 'game_setup2_schedule' %}"> {% csrf_token %}
                <div><strong>Select 3 Weight Training Days</strong></div>
                <div>{{ form.weight_training_days}}</div>
                <div><strong>Select 3 Cardio Days</strong></div>
                <div>{{ form.cardio_training_days }}</div>
                <div><button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" type="submit">&nbsp;Next</button></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

{% endblock %}

Answer (score 7):

When forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple is rendered it is rendered in a ul tag . What you need to do is add the following to your css (making it more specific to that form as required):

```
ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: perfect! I appreciate the help.

Comment: Any way to define it in the form class?

Answer (score 5):

This removes the bullet point without adding css. :)

```
{% for checkbox in form.Context %}
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
            {{ checkbox.tag }} {{ checkbox.choice_label }}
    </label>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Dude! Finally I come across what I was looking for a while to override the CheckboxSelectMultiple in templates.
This resolve mine, despite it was not for <ul> list-style-type

Answer (score 0):

I found it easiest to define in form class

```
widget= forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(
        attrs={
            'class': "list-unstyled"
        }
    )
```